# Running Java program in a Docker Image

Tags: java, docker, runtime, hyperledger-sawtooth

So I have a Docker network that has a Docker file with a bunch of information. I have a java program that is going to bring up the enviorment and then produce several commands to run within this enviorment. To be clear, the first command I need to run is NOT inside the Docker enviorment.  I am having some challenges with the Process and Runtime classes.

First, say I wanted my java program to launch a new gnome terminal and then run a command to get into the docker network. I have this command,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal"});
```

Gnome terminal sucessfully comes up but any additional arguments I give in this array are just ignored. For example,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal","ls"});
```

Does not work. The command I ultimatly want to run would look something like this,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal","sudo","docker","exec","-it","sawtooth-shell-default", "bash"});
```

Second, Once I have this running, will additional commmands I run work within the Docker enviorment? I have a python file with a Stream handler that specifies the correct commands to run.
Other documentation on related issues was limited.

I made sure my code was wrapped in a runtime exception try catch and that I was running the correct .class file. Any help on this would be great!

Edit: I have also tried to run this in another linux terminal like Hyper and Tilda

I also am able to get a sudo sign in when I run the command like so,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal","--","sudo","docker","exec","-it","sawtooth-shell-default", "bash"});
```

However it closes immediatly after authorizing.

Comment: Try `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal","--","ls"});` also, running a gnome-terminal in a docker image seems like the wrong way to go about things.

Comment: If you are running that command from a Java process running inside a Docker image, then you are also running that command inside the Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what I was attempting to do.
https://www.atlassian.com/blog/software-teams/deploy-java-apps-with-docker-awesome
This site is outdated and I had to use this link for getting that latest version of the java PPA.

This process basically installs java into the docker contatiner so that I can run a java program that uses Runtime.